# Kibana docker compose with external elastic search

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I've the following docker compose file. I'm trying to connect elastic search running in another machine to kibana.

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  kibana_ci:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.3.2
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://my_domain:9200
    container_name: kibana_ci
    command: kibana
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
```

But kibana is keep trying to connect to `http://elasticsearch:9200/` url. I've also tried with following options which didnt work.

```
    environment:
      - "ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://my_domain:9200"
    environment:
      - "KIBANA_ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://my_domain:9200"
    environment:
      KIBANA_ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://my_domain:9200
    environment:
      elasticsearch.url: http://my_domain:9200
```

How can I change the url in docker compose file (without overriding kibana.yml file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This compose file works for me:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.3.2
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: kibana.example.org
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://my_domain
```

You don't need to define default port `9200`.

```
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-20T16:58:31Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://my_domain:9200/"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-20T16:58:31Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-20T16:58:34Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://my_domain:9200/"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-20T16:58:34Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
```

Comment: I've removed command from my config. it started working even with port.

Answer (score 1):

For those who will face the same issue in `Kibana 7.5`, you will have to use the `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS` environment variable instead of `ELASTICSEARCH_URL`, like below:

```
kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.5.2
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://es01:9200
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - es01
    networks:
      - elastic
```

You can also consult via the following link the list of all environment variables available, and how to setup in a docker environment:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.5/docker.html